# How can I replace strings between a pattern for an NSString?

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsstring

Consider an NSString of the following pattern:

```
(foo('Class 0')bar('Class 1')baz('Class 2')
```

I just need to return `foo`, `bar` and `baz`. Any way I could at least replace `'Class 0'` to some single character using regex?

I tried:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\(.*?\\)"
                                                                         options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                           error:nil];
text = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:text options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [text length]) withTemplate:@""];
```

Comment: Your question is asking about two conflicting approaches. Do you want to return the three strings or do you actually want to replace the `('Class X')` parts with a space or something? In other words, do you want an array with the 3 strings or do you want a single string with `"foo bar baz"`?

Comment: The latter - `foo bar baz`

Comment: And is that leading `(` just before `foo` actually part of the string that you wish to modify?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your situation correctly, you needed to parse `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` out of the string above. The code below will do just that, and return `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` in an array.

As you will see in the code, we match on a word and an opening paren, and then trim the parens off programmatically. There may be a better regex that doesn't require the trimming, but I couldn't make that work with **NSRegularExpression**.

```
NSString *text = @"(foo('Class 0')bar('Class 1')baz('Class 2')";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[a-z]+[\(]"
                                          options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                            error:nil];

NSMutableArray *output = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[regex enumerateMatchesInString:text
                        options:0
                          range:NSMakeRange(0, [text length])
                     usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult * _Nullable result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

                         NSString *rawMatch = [text substringWithRange:result.range];
                         NSString *trimmed = [rawMatch substringToIndex:(rawMatch.length - 1)];
                         [output addObject:trimmed];
                     }];
```

To get a string, like the one you mention in your comment above, just use

```
NSString *finalString = [output componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use:

```
NSString *string = @"foo('Class 0')bar('Class 1')baz('Class 2')";
NSString *output = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\('[^')]*'\\)"
                                                     withString:@" "
                                                        options:NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                                          range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];
NSLog(@"%@", output); // foo bar baz
```

Replacing anything between `('` and `')` with a space. The pattern `[^')]` means that we don't want `)` and `'`letters to appear in between.